# scrapy - How to insert hierarchical items to database?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm asking about [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) framework.

I'm scraping a business page. First I add Brand Item (I have Brands table) with business name, then I want add several business locations (BusinessLocations table) but I need database BrandId to insert business location to database. Then I add few records about departments for each business location and again I need database BusinessLocationId to insert each Department.

Let's assume I insert Items to database in pipeline.

**Can I simply assume that items processed earlier already left pipeline and are in database?** In this case I can simply select needed Id's from database using some text unique field passed via meta data.

However I suppose there might be race condition since scrapy process multiple requests simultaneously. By race condition I mean that BusinessLocation item is being added before appropriate Brand is inserted to database. **Is there a risk of that kind of race condition?**

Answer (score 1):

> Can I simply assume that items processed earlier already left pipeline and are in database?

Generally, no.

It highly highly on what you do in the pipeline. For example, if you use the images pipeline, then the items with images will be hold by the images pipeline until all the images are retrieved meanwhile an item with no images or very few images will pass to the next pipeline before the previous item.

You could collect the sub-items in the main item object passing around the item to the sub-requests, but then you will have to care about whether to handle the errors to not lose an incomplete item. Another approach can be storing the items in a staging database and later consolidate looking for orphan records.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution how to wait, until all data are scraped - close_spider method of pipeline is called after spider is closed.

```
class BlsPipeline100(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.items.append(item)
        return item

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        processAllItems()
```

Now I can create hierarchy having all items accessible.